# How to get the time to first byte from Azure AKS using Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I need to get the response time metrics from AKS using Azure Application Gateway. I've tried searching it up in the dashboard, but metrics like response time (Time to first byte, Time to last byte etc) are not directly accessible from the AKS Cluster monitoring and metrics dashboard. How do I get these metrics directly into my AKS Cluster, if possible or atleast query it using the Azure Monitor Workbooks?

Really appreciate any help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your entry is based on AGIC, this is the best place to retrieve this information.

You can retrieve this information in Azure Monitor if your AGIC sends logs to Azure Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If this data normally available in prometheus metrics?

if so, you could also onboard to Prometheus in azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/prometheus-metrics-overview

once that is on, you can query Prometheus via PromQL in workbooks as a query data source.